# How to close ngx-dialog on api response using angular7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an `angular` application in which i have implemented `ngx-dialogs` as delete item confirmation dialog box and it's working correctly. It prompts to user before deleting and when user click on "Yes" so it deletes the item from the list but i want to close that dialog automatically on delete api response.

Here is my `component.ts` code in which i am creating dialog inside my `delete` function like this

```js
delete = (rowData: Category) => {
    if (rowData) {
        this.confirmAlert.create({
            title: 'Delete Warning',
            message: 'Are you sure, you want to delete Company?',
            confirm: () => {
                this._utilityService.showSpinner();
                this._dataService.delete(this._const.category + '/' + rowData._id).subscribe((delres: any) => {
                    console.log('Self Category Delete Response : ', delres);
                    this._utilityService.hideSpinner();
                    delres.success ? this._utilityService.showToster(delres.message, 'Notification', 'success') : this._utilityService.showToster(delres.message, 'Notification', 'danger');
                    this.reset();
                    this.getCategory();
                }, (error: any) => {
                    this._utilityService.hideSpinner();
                    console.log('Self Category Delete Error : ', error);
                    this._utilityService.showToster('Having some issue, Please try later!', 'Warning', 'warning')
                    this.reset();
                    this.getCategory();
                })
            },
        })
    }
}
```

Note : When i tried this

```
document.querySelector('.ngx-dialog').style.display = "none"
```

in delete api response so it shows an error like this

```
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'
```

How can i close this dialog after delete `api` response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer for my problem. When i was trying to get element by javascript like this

```
document.querySelector('.ngx-dialog')).style.display = "none"
```

so i was getting the erorr like this

```
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'
```

so after that i tried this and it worked for me perfectly

```
(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.ngx-dialog')).style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

The function which is getting executed after the click, write a query code that can fetch the dialog tag using `document.querySelector('.dialog')` then you can call the hide method if your dialog has it otherwise you can create your own hide method.

For example: -
`<button ngClick=(deleteRecord(id)>Delete</button>`
If this button is present in my dialog. Then inside of that function you can write

```
deleteRecord(id: int) {
// pass the id or class name of your dialog
const dialog = (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.dialog'))

// after API returns the success for deletion of your record
if(response_of_api === 'success') {
 dialog.hide() // if your dialog has a hide function

// or
dialog.style.display = 'none'
 }
}
```

In your case, this concept can be applied after below line

```
console.log('Self Category Delete Response : ', delres);
```

Comment: when i am trying to access `ngx-dialog` box class like this `document.querySelector('.ngx-dialog').style` so it says `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'` so what should i do now?

Comment: Try adding your own custom class name to that model and fetch it in the query with that name. Or if it does not work then typecast it using `<HTMLElement>`. If this helps then you can upvote my answer for other users.

Comment: Before your comment i solved my problem myself by adding `<HTMLElement>` because in your orignal answer you didn't include about `<HTMLElement>` so why should i up vote for your answer because it didn't work for me

Comment: Dude but you got 90% solution from my answer. But anyways your issue is solved that's what matters. :)